# HttpGet/Client and HTTPS

Tags: java, android, https

Previously, I used custom TrustManager talked about [here](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/ssl.html) to do this

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
MyXMLHandler mHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(mHandler);

xr.parse(new InputSource(buildUrlString()));
```

(where buildUrlString() returns a string containing the https:// url to call) which works fine.  However, I want to now be able to send the same url an Accept-Encoding header for gzip compression.  I can do that like this

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(buildUrlString());
request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
if ((contentEncoding != null)
    && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) 
{ 
  instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
} 
xr.parse(new InputSource(instream));
```

but that brings back the "Not trusted server certificate" error that I want to ignore.  How do I make it do HTTPS?  Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?  (And is there something I need to check first to make sure the phone really can accept the gzipped webpages that I'm saying it can?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Apache HTTP client API you can keep using your custom TrustManager by extending the DefaultHttpClient

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
  final Context context;

  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override 
  protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }

  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      TrustManager tm = new MyCustomTrustManager();
      SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm}, null);
      SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
      return new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have not tested this solution but it is inspired by Bob Lee blog post http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually this works:

```
URL url = new URL(buildUrlString());
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip"); 

InputStream instream = conn.getInputStream();
String response = conn.getContentEncoding();
if ((response != null)
    && response.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) 
{ 
  instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
} 
xr.parse(new InputSource(instream));
```

I'm still not sure this is the best solution, though, so I'll leave the question up for a bit in case anyone has better ideas. :)